# Creat or Open not working. Please suggest

Tags: c, io-redirection

Doing something very simple..
Running this simple code to create a dir and file (if not exists) but is not working. Running in chmod 0777.Trying to redirect the output to a file. trying for this command.

ls tests/source>/tmp/temp.txt

created below program.I ran it with only file name it worked but not with prefix /tmp.

```
 char *filename = "/tmp/temp.txt";
 printf("A %d\n",getpid());
 int fd;
 if((fd = open(filename,O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,0777)) < 0)
  printf("Error:%s",strerror(errno));
 
 pid_t child = fork(); 
 if(child == 0){  
 dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);
 }
 printf("B %d\n",getpid());
 close(fd);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: its not creating tmp folder and temp file in it. Not throwing any error also. But when I went to filesystem, in working directory nothing is there..but when i remove the /tmp from the file file is getting created..

Comment: It is not supposed to be in working directory, it is supposed to be in `/tmp`.

Comment: sorry if my earlier statement caused any confusion. Let me put this in a simple way..Is it possible to create directory as tmp and file inside it (temp.txt) with any one library function. or I need to parse the filename fetch the dir and create using mkdir and then create file using fopen.